# Matplotlib Quiver hides small arrows?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

It seems like matplotlib's quiver is not plotting arrows below a certain size.

When I plot the uniform field [1,1,1] arrows appear everywhere. When I change to the field I want to plot, only the area with large vectors shows. I tested thoroughly to make sure the field was nonzero in the ungraphed region.

When I multiply the lengths of every vector (including the large ones) by 10, more of the field shows. When I multiply by 100, all arrows show. This suggests an absolute cutoff for a vector's size.

I could not find any info about this feature. Is it intentional / can it be turned off? I'd like to see the whole vector field.

The basic plot commands I used are below:

```
vector_fig=plt.figure(3)
vector_ax=vector_fig.gca(projection="3d")
vector_ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=1.3)
```

Comment: What kind of range of values does `get_B` result in?

Comment: Also, in my opinion, posting such incomplete and complicated pieces of code isn't going to help you. With a minimal working example it is much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Testing 1 million random points over the plotted region shows the min and max to be 5e-13 and 3e-10, respectively. Sorry about the code - I will look through it now and throw away all but the relevant parts.

Comment: Interesting note: When I multiply the entire field by 100, the arrows all show again. Hopefully there's a better way than this workaround?

Comment: Might I recommend, just for testing purposes, that you try adjusting the scaling of your arrows? Here are [some samples in the `matplotlib` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/quiver_demo.html) for the use of the `quiverkey` function alongside `quiver` - try each different scaling technique, and maybe more to see what works best for your dataset. I think that you should just choose something to scale the arrows by so that none of the arrows are significantly smaller (such that you can't see them on the plot) than the rest.

Comment: @VladislavMartin Thanks, I'll check those out! I do think that it's not about relative size though, since multiplying every arrow by 100 plots them all. It seems to be an absolute size cutoff.

Comment: I see. Well, it's hard to tell from just a word explanation what you're seeing. Could you attach 1) the plot that doesn't show the smaller arrows and 2) the 100x scaled plot that shows all the arrows? By the way, you might consider showing how you get `x`, `y`, `z`, `u`, `v`, and `w` just because they're directly relevant to your plot.